# How to write a common public function to load Admob ad for Activity, ListActivity and PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, admob

The Code 1 and the Code 2 has repeated code.  I tried to write a common public function Code 3 and invoke the function in Code 1 and Code 2.

But a common public function `SetAD` in the code doesn't work, the `adView = (AdView)myContext.findViewById(R.id.adView)` causes an error.  What can I do? Thanks!

**Code 1**

```
public class CallerMain extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);

        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.IsRegistered)==false) {
            adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                         .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                         .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }   

    }   

}
```

**Code 2**

```
public class CallPreference extends PreferenceActivity{
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.callpreference);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_custom_preference);

        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.IsRegistered) == false) {
            adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
                    AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

    }   

}
```

**Code 3**

```
public class PublicParFun {

    public static void SetAD(AdView adView,Context myContext){  
        if (myContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.IsRegistered)==false) {
            adView = (AdView)myContext.findViewById(R.id.adView);  //Case error
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                         .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                         .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error is casued?

Comment: adView = (AdView)myContext.findViewById(R.id.adView) cause error, myContext havn't method findViewById

Comment: It should pass Activity to the method too, findViewById is a method in Activity

Comment: But there are PreferenceActivity, ListActivity in main layout , can I force to covert them into Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you don't need to a `Context` at all. you can even do this by only one argument passing to the `SetAD` function. In my opinion passing `Activity` object to this function is not a good practice. Because doing so might violate [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

As its obvious the responsibility of this function is setting some advertise on a `AdView`. This responsibility does not include obtaining reference of `AdView` from activities. (Suppose another activity chose a different ID for the `AdView`)

So, this general function should be modified to:

```
public class PublicParFun {

    public static void setAdIfNotRegistered(AdView adView){
        if(adView.getContext().getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.IsRegistered) == false)
            SetAD(adView);
    }    

    public static void SetAD(AdView adView){  
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

Usage in code 1 (similar for code 2)

```
public class CallerMain extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caller_main);

        PublicParFun.setAdIfNotRegistered((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Your code do work, but I don't understand why I can use (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView) and adView.getContext().

Comment: @HelloCW I'm glad that helped you, I've moved `(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView)` to the activity `onCreate` because it related to that activity (it is included in activity responsibility not that general function). and `adView.getContext()` is a way to obtain context from an existing view.

Comment: @HelloCW you can move `(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView)` to that general function and no error would be happening but it violate that priciple which I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Thanks!  Does it mean that all Activity, ListActivity and PreferenceActivity layout can use (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView)? and is Adview the parent of Activity, ListActivity and PreferenceActivity ?

Comment: @HelloCW All activities which have a `AdView` can pass their adview to that general. / your second question: No, Activities are parent of their contents (i.e. all view that they have)

Comment: @HelloCW one activity maybe have a adview whith id `adview1` so this activity should use `(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView1)` and another activity which have a adview with id `adview2` should use `(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView2)` Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the inheritance tree:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.app.ListActivity
                       ↳    android.preference.PreferenceActivity
```

As you can see both `PreferenceActivity` and `Activity` inherit from Context but, `findViewById` method becomes available only at class `Activity`.

And from OOP basics, we know, that a class can be cast to it's parent class without any problems, therefore both `PreferenceActivity` and `Activity` can be *cast* to `Activity` and make the method `findViewById` available.

**tl;dr** Just change your method's parameter from Context to Activity:

```
public class PublicParFun {
    public static void SetAD(AdView adView, Activity myContext){
        ...
    }
}
```